# Draw marker on Flutter Google map

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I'm beginner. I have small problem on my project. My project simply draw maker(s) on the google map.

This is a part of code to draw the map

```
child: GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(-33.852, 151.211),
                zoom: 2.0,
              ),
              markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
              // __addmarker(),
            ),
```

I create a `void _addmarker()` for  and a button to add marker. Like this

```
//void _addmarker()
Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      position: LatLng(
        11.052992, 106.681612,  
      ),
```

Code of Button

```
FlatButton(
  child: const Text('add'),
  onPressed: _addmarker,
),
```

It's mean when I `onPressed`, the map will draw marker with Lat,Lng on `void _addmarker()`

It's OK but now I want draw marker on the map but no need press button.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

So now you are adding your markers with a button and function and you want to add them without pressing a button?

You can create Set of markers on your state widget.

`Set<Marker> markers = Set();`

And then you can fill that Set of markers in your build method,

```
markers.addAll([
  Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('value'),
      position: LatLng(37.416780, -122.077430)),
  Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('value2'),
      position: LatLng(37.416000, -122.077000)),
]);
```

There is also various constructor methods for Set class. You can just use one, you don't have to add them.
[Set class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Set-class.html)
And then you can pass that filled set to your Google Maps widget.

```
child: GoogleMap(
                  onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                  myLocationEnabled: true,
                  initialCameraPosition:
                      CameraPosition(target: LatLng(0.0, 0.0)),
                  markers: markers,
                ))),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Set of markers function like this:

```
Future<Set<Marker>> myMarkers() async {
     List<Marker> mMarkers = [];
     mMarkers.add(
       Marker(
         markerId: MarkerId('marker1'),
         position: LatLng(15.392567, 44.278188),
       ),
     );
     mMarkers.add(
       Marker(
         markerId: MarkerId('marker1'),
         position: LatLng(15.392029, 44.278113),
       ),
     );
  
     return mMarkers.toSet();
   }
```

and you can use this function in `FutureBuilder` widget like this:

````
FutureBuilder(
 future: myMarkers(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
   return GoogleMap(
     mapType: MapType.normal,
     initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
     markers: snapshot.data,
   );
  },
 ),
```
````